# Xcode logging only previously selected table view cell once a new cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a table view and each time I select a new select, it logs the stats of the cell selected before it.

So let's say I select cell B, it won't log anything if that's the first cell I've selected since opening the table view. But if I then select cell A, it will log the stats of cell B.. then if I select cell C it will log cell A's stats, etc.

Any idea why?

Code below:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

FeedItem *feedItem = [[FeedItem alloc] init];
feedItem = [self.feedItemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@ username", feedItem.username);
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but there's no reason to alloc-init your `FeedItem`.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure, if you had added a breakpoint to the function and verified what happened to feedItem, it would be clear what the problem is.

Comment: Can you share what you are using for cellForIndex method.. It seems that you are using array in a different way to show table cell value and differently when reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong method. You want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Yours is `Deselect` instead of `Select`

Comment: Exactly. Happens all the time since didDeselect comes way before didSelect in the autocompletion drop down in XCode ...

Comment: Not only way before it, but `didSelect` doesn't show up in the first screen of auto-complete options. You have to scroll down after typing in `- (void)table` to even see it